# VLOOKUP using dynamic workbooks in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How do I capture a new workbook (with link location) using VBA and automatically run VLOOKUP to get the data and populate a table in another workbook?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It's hard to understand exactly what you want here. Could you please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/807395/edit) your question to include more detail? It would be helpful to explain what you mean by "capture a new workbook". Where does the new workbook come from? Is it generated from code? Maybe provide a full example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: I have workbook1 that will need to be updated with information from a workbook2 that gets generated bi-weekly.  Workbook1 has a table that uses VLOOKUP to get data from workbook2.  I would like to know if I can use VBA to automate the part where I am changing the VLOOKUP formula to define the newly generated workbook2 and dragging the formula to all the cells to populate the table in workbook1.

Comment: Is the name of the workbook2 is always the same, is the data range it contains always the same? When workbook2 is created does it have named range for the data. If there is consistency, or if you can always name a working copy of workbook2 the same, you can probably define it's data range and your vlookup formulas can remain unchanged.

Comment: thanks! that's what I had in mind but wanted to be sure it's possible and will work as I have not tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use edit links on Workbook 1 to change the links to the new workbook.  The new workbook will need to be in the same format (sheet names and cell positions) as the previous one.

Comment: thanks! that's what I had in mind but wanted to be sure it's possible and will work as I have not tried it before.  I'm not sure I understand the edit links part though, kindly advise.  thanks again!